# Displaying ID on dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css

So, I have the following set up of a dropdown menu:

https://jsfiddle.net/mboz45fv/10/

What I am trying to achieve is that, when `sub menu` is clicked, I want to display the title of `sub menu` in the `Menu` space as shown below.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
So, I realized that I was not clear enough.

Let say, an user clicks `Sub Menu 2` button, then the user will be directed to that page.

This `sub menu 2` page will have `url` of `sub_menu_2`. 
For example, the page `url` will be `.com/sub_menu_2`

I want the `menu` title to be `sub menu 2` when the users are in the `sub menu 2` page.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your edit is completely another question.

Comment: Please expand on "that page will have `id` of".  Do you mean url?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that my initial question was not clear. I missed the key point in the initial question.

Comment: I am going to just open up a new question as it was not clear enough. Thanks guys =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/mboz45fv/3/

Add a class to your main as well as sub menu's and set the value as shown below,

```
<h1>Drop Down Menu</h1>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>

  <li><a class="main-menu" href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="sub-menu" id="a" href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="sub-menu" id="d" href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="sub-menu" id="c" href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>
</nav>

$('.sub-menu').on('click', function(){
    $('.main-menu').text($(this).text())
});
```

EDIT: If you want the 'Menu' text back when the user is not focusing on the control, here is the solution:https://jsfiddle.net/mboz45fv/9/

Comment: Hi. I realized that I was not clear enough. I am trying to call the `id` onto the `title` section when the user is in that particular page if that makes sens (See edited version above). Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Without changing HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li ul li a').click(function(e){
        $('#primary_nav_wrap > ul > li > a').text($(this).text());
    });
});
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/mboz45fv/7/

Comment: Hi. I realized that I was not clear enough. I am trying to call the id onto the title section when the user is in that particular page if that makes sens (See edited version above). Sorry for the confusion